# Collections are going into loop

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

I want to update the table, however, collections are going into a loop. Need to update 500 000 records, but it is taking a lot of time..if something can be done..

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROC_ACCOUNT_STATUS AS
  CURSOR C1 IS 
    SELECT ACCOUNTS1, 
           abs((PREVIOUS_DELINQUENCIES - CURRENT_DELINQUENCIES)) AS DIFF_DEL 
    FROM TEMP_LOAN;

  TYPE COLL_ACCOUNT_STATUS IS TABLE OF C1%ROWTYPE;
  COLL_STAB1 COLL_ACCOUNT_STATUS := COLL_ACCOUNT_STATUS();
  COLL_STAB2 COLL_ACCOUNT_STATUS := COLL_ACCOUNT_STATUS();
BEGIN
  OPEN C1;
  LOOP
    FETCH C1 BULK COLLECT INTO COLL_STAB2 LIMIT 500;
    EXIT WHEN COLL_STAB2.COUNT = 0;
    COLL_STAB1 := COLL_STAB2;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE C1;

  FOR I IN 1..COLL_STAB1.COUNT
  LOOP
    IF(COLL_STAB1(I).DIFF_DEL>=30) AND(COLL_STAB1(I).DIFF_DEL>=31) THEN
      COLL_STAB1.EXTEND();
      COLL_STAB1(COLL_STAB1.COUNT):=COLL_STAB1(I);
    END IF;
  END LOOP;

  FORALL I IN 1..COLL_STAB1.COUNT
    UPDATE TEMP_LOAN 
    SET ACCOUNT_STATUS = 'STAB' 
    WHERE ACCOUNTS1 = COLL_STAB1(I).ACCOUNTS1;

  COLL_STAB1.DELETE;
  COLL_STAB2.DELETE;
  COMMIT;
END;
```

Comment: Is this your actual code (rather than some redacted code you've invented to post here)? Because it doesn't seem to make much sense. There seems to be a lot of unnecessary processing, which would eat up the time. Perhaps you can explain the business rules you're trying to implement, and we can provide a better way of achieving that.

Comment: 500,000 isn’t really that much, you should be able to do that many row lookups in less than a minute really. That said, you are going to be updating every row in this table so why bother with looped updates? APC’s answer would be the preferred route if you can. If you must do procedural logic and do the update per row then you might just be missing a crucial index on that filtered column.

Comment: @AndrewSayer for 500K updates the *usage of index* is the *crucial think* - well if you don't not have a 1hour+ time to wait for the result...

Comment: I'm intrigued by `substr((previous_delinquencies - current_delinquencies),2)`. Say `previous_delinquencies` is 42 and `current_delinquencies` is 40. That evaluates to `substr('2',2)`, which is null. Is that really the business logic?

Comment: @APC ..yes this is the actual code and the business rule is simple whatever the IF condition is if it is getting satisfied on the basis of that column should get's updated........if there is any alternative for reducing the time by removing unwanted code..please guide..

Comment: @WilliamRobertson...u can ignore that substr thing because I just found the alternate of this using ABS ....ABS((previous_delinquencies - current_delinquencies))

Comment: Also note that `bulk collect` replaces the contents of the collection for every loop iteration, so at the end of the first loop it only contains the results from the last fetch.

Answer (score 2):

What is wrong with a straightforward update?

```
update temp_loan
set ACCOUNT_STATUS = 'STAB' 
WHERE SUBSTR((PREVIOUS_DELINQUENCIES - CURRENT_DELINQUENCIES),2) >= 31
```

---

Possibly this is not the answer you want, especially if (as per my comment) the logic you posted in the question is not representative of the logic you actually are implementing.